# Flex: Which way should I add this event handler?

Tags: apache-flex

I use a unit of work pattern a lot in my flex projects.  I'll have a class that might call a web service, put the data in a sqlite db, refresh a model with the data then raise an event.

I usually call these inline and pass in some singleton classes:

```
protected function CareerSynced():void
    {
        var process:ProcessWorkouts = new ProcessWorkouts(_dataModel, _trainerModel, _databaseCache, _database.Conn);
        process.addEventListener("AllWorkoutsProcessed", AllWorkoutsProcessed);
        process.UpdateAllUnprocessed();
    }
```

I'll then get the response like this:

```
private function AllWorkoutsProcessed(event:DataReceivedEvent):void
    {
    //do something here 
    }
```

My question is, am I adding that event listener correctly?  I think I might be causing a memory leak, but I'm not sure.  I've also thought about using a weak reference.  I'm confused about when to use them.   Would this be one of those cases?

Should it be like this?

`process.addEventListener("AllWorkoutsProcessed", AllWorkoutsProcessed,false, 0, true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either go with the weak reference or just remove the listener:

```
private function AllWorkoutsProcessed(event:DataReceivedEvent):void
{
     event.target.removeEventListener("AllWorksoutsProcessed",AllWorkoutsProcessed);
}
```

I could list out my reasons but I'll just point you to [this](http://www.selikoff.net/2010/09/21/flex-event-handlers-and-weak-references/).